# get current workflow name within custom activity

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Hello I'm creating a custom workflow action for sharepoint 2010 using c# but I would like to re-use the same action but adjust the code slightly depending on which workflow it is fired from. Is there a way to get the workflow name? Or any other unique identifier?

Thanks